# Asp.net MVC Route Mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have view names like Folder-One/Page-One.aspx I want to do a base controller implimentation that all request go to one Base Controller, that returns the view based on the context. Obviously still keeping the .aspx in the path

I have folders like getting-started/application-faq.aspx but what I want to do is I want to create 1 controller that does all the return views, as the pages are basicly static html

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{view}.aspx",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Base", action = "ChooseView" ,view ="Page-One"}  
        );
```

and your action can choose view to show :

```
publict ActionResult ChooseView (string viewName)
```

{
  return View("~/Views/"+viewName);
}